# How to position divs on top of one another

Tags: html, css

I want to position divs on top of one another. I have created  a fiddle. I have three divs. Each div contains an image. I want to position divs so that the div having the largest image is at the bottom and the one having smallest image is on top.

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/7spcZ/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/7spcZ/2/show/

Comment: Just put img { position: absolute; }​

Comment: Do you need to calculate the image size and depending on that, you want to position them or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use position absolute with z-index.

use below css

```
#page-left {
float: left;
margin:5px;
}

#page-right {
float: left;
margin:5px;
}

#largest {
position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
#medium {
position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
#smallest {
position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sannankhalid/sc8qE/

Comment: you answer is nice because you have nicely defined the z-index value if somenbdy wants to understand the use of z-index they can easily understand gud job....@Khali

Answer (score 5):

Just use this:

```
#page1 div {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZwyTY/

Answer (score 1):

Just use `position : absolute;`

```
#largest, #medium, #smallest{
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4WBk/

If you want to change the order of what comes on top, you can use [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `z-index` & `position: absolute` to treat the elements as layers. But as per your requirement and element order, a simple `position: absolute` is enough

```css
#page1 div {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just change the order of the div's? Either that or target each one with position relative.

Answer (score 0):

you can only define the absolute position into your main div that will automatically call the images as orderd or coded in your HTML here is no-need to use z-index in your css as per current your requirement.

**CSS**

```
#page1 div {
position:absolute;
}
```

But if you will change the order of **#largest,#medium,#smallest div's** in your HTML code than you will have to define the z-index property for cover up the images as:-

**HTML**

```
<div id ="page1">
           <div id = "smallest">
               <img src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/pongoproductions.Brad_Pitt_100100/hi-256-0-acd81f6f98299f7b230fc5014a9eb18c536adc8a"/>
            </div>                                
           <div id = "medium">
               <img src="http://www.picgifs.com/celebrities/b/brad-pitt/celebrities-brad-pitt-179755.jpg"/>
           </div>               
            <div id = "largest">
               <img src="http://www.moviespad.com/photos/brad-pitt-poster-392f6.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#page1 div {
position: absolute;
}

#largest {
    z-index: 1;
}
#medium {
    z-index: 2;
}
#smallest {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9cg3h/